# Ant propertyregex, replace only the last occurrence?

Tags: ant

Let's say I have a package `abc.bcd.html.efg.Hello.html`, I want to tear down the `.html` extension without changing the package. How do I do it?

Comment: Package? No idea what you're asking...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a regex like

```
(.*)\.html$
```

(the dollar matching the end of the input string).  This would correspond to

```
<propertyregex property="some.property" input="abc.bcd.html.efg.Hello.html"
    regex="(.*)\.html$$" select="\1" />
```

using a double dollar to "escape" the single dollar sign from being treated as part of a property expansion by ant - see ["$$ Expansion" on this page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html).